# What kind of fence is used at this British airfield?

Tags: world-war-two, england

I am just working on a colorization of a Heinkel He 162. To get the color right, I have to know what kind of fence is used on the airfield. My best guess would be wood, but it can also be metal.

Is there someone who knows what this could be?

**EDIT:** [I found out](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45340/what-are-these-wheel-chocks-made-of-and-what-color-do-they-most-probably-have) that the He 162, Werksnummer 120086, as seen in the photo, has been "caught" by the British and therefore, this is a photo captured on a British airfield.

[image: He 162]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks a lot like a [wood paling](http://tate-fencing.co.uk/product/cleft-chestnut-paling/) fence, which is wooden stakes linked by wire.

[image]

Comment: Nice to know that not everything was over-engineered.

Comment: Looks like they are mounted on metal-axled frames however, unlike in your diagram. The axles look as though they are machined dead straight, while the banisters are somewhat irregular as in your picture above.